# Lightning Div with multiple if condition

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

this is my div's onclick code:

```
onclick="{!if(and(calendarDay.active,v.enableCalendarClickedEvent,v.calendarClickedEventType=='calendarDay'),c.handleClick,'')}"
```

The problem is that only the first two condition in AND are evaluated.. For example:

- calendarDay.active turns TRUE
- enableCalendarClickedEvent  turns TRUE
- calendarClickedEventType turns FALSE

I expect the if do nothing, but it acts like condition are all TRUE..
If i change the order of the condition, it ignore always the last one.
So, maybe it's a syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a syntax error, but rather a limitation of how expressions operate. AND and OR only accept two parameters, so you have to nest them together:

```
onclick="{!if(and(calendarDay.active,and(v.enableCalendarClickedEvent,v.calendarClickedEventType=='calendarDay')),c.handleClick,'')}"
```